# ASP Classic Paypal Integration flow and issues

Tags: paypal, asp-classic, integration

I need some clarity with regard to Paypal integration.
 Firstly I have done a successful classic ASP Paypal integration about three years ago which worked just fine.
 I have used that in conjunction with the current Paypal documentation to produce a new system for a client. I can't get it working.

Here is what I am doing:

Step 1: I have a basket of items (in this case, show tickets).

Step 2: I capture the users address and contact details in my own form.

Step 3: I call the 'expresscheckout.asp' form downloaded from Paypal Developer API

Here is the first bit of code on that Form:

```
 <%
 v_title        = Request.Form("title")
 v_firstname    = Request.Form("firstname")
 v_lastname     = Request.Form("lastname")
 v_addrline1    = Request.Form("addrline1")
 v_addrline2    = Request.Form("addrline2")
 v_addrline3    = Request.Form("addrline3")
 v_addrline4    = Request.Form("addrline4")
 v_addrcity     = Request.Form("addrcity")
 v_addrcounty   = Request.Form("addrcounty")
 v_addrpostcode = Request.Form("addrpostcode")
 v_countryid    = Request.Form("countryid")
 v_currencyid   = Request.Form("currencyid")
 v_phoneprimary = Request.Form("phoneprimary")
 v_email        = Request.Form("email")

 SQLStmt = "UPDATE [OrderHeader] SET [Title] = '" & v_title & "',[FirstName] = '" & v_firstname & "',[LastName] = '" & v_lastname & "',[AddrLine1] = '" & v_addrline1 & "',[AddrLine2] = '" & v_addrline2 & "',[AddrLine3] = '" & v_addrline3 & "',[AddrLine4] = '" & v_addrline4 & "',[AddrCity] = '" & v_addrcity & "',[AddrCounty] = '" & v_addrcounty & "',AddrPostcode='" & v_addrpostcode & "',CountryId=" & v_countryid & ",CurrencyId=" & v_currencyid & ",PhonePrimary='" & v_phoneprimary & "',Email='" & v_email & "', Status='New' WHERE [OrderReference] = '" & session("orderreference") & "';"
 Set RS_OrderHeader01 = Connection01.Execute(SQLStmt)

On Error Resume Next
paymentAmount = Session("Payment_Amount")
currencyCodeType = "GBP"
paymentType = "Sale"
returnURL = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/transactioncomplete.asp"
cancelURL = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/shop.asp"

%>
```

As you can see I am capturing my users input details and updating my OrderHeader and then setting up the Paypal Variables. I can confirm 'paymentAmount' is set correctly.

The next section of code on the same form is:

```
<%
Set resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout (paymentAmount, currencyCodeType, paymentType, returnURL, cancelURL)

ack = UCase(resArray("ACK"))
If ack="SUCCESS" Then
 ' Redirect to paypal.com
 SQLStmt = "UPDATE [OrderHeader] SET [Token] = '" & resArray("TOKEN") & "' WHERE [OrderReference] = '" & session("orderreference") & "';"
 Set RS_OrderHeader01 = Connection01.Execute(SQLStmt)
 ReDirectURL(resArray("TOKEN") )
Else
 'Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
 ErrorCode = URLDecode( resArray("L_ERRORCODE0"))
 ErrorShortMsg = URLDecode( resArray("L_SHORTMESSAGE0"))
 ErrorLongMsg = URLDecode( resArray("L_LONGMESSAGE0"))
 ErrorSeverityCode = URLDecode( resArray("L_SEVERITYCODE0"))
%>
   <div class="content full left">
    <h1>Payment Not Succesful</h1>
    <p>Your order number is &nbsp;<span class="bold"><%=session("orderreference")%></span>. Please use this number if you need to contact us about this order.
   </div>
   <div class="content full left">
    <h2>There was a problem with your payment.</h2>
    <p>Please contact us with your order reference and following details so that we can help you complete the transaction.</p>
    <p>Paypal error code: <%=ErrorCode%></p>
    <p>Error description: <%=ErrorLongMsg%></p>
    <p>Severity: <%=ErrorSeverityCode%></p>
   </div>
<%
End If
%>
```

As you can see from this I am making the call to 'CallShortcutExpressCheckout'. I can confirm that the TOKEN is returned correctly and I update my Orderheader with it.

So far, so good.

However at this point I am redirected to a Payal page that has a blank order summary.
As soon as I enter my sandbox buyer account details I get spat out to my ReturnURL.

The code on my Return URL is here:

```
<%
 Session("orderreference") = ""
 On Error Resume Next
 finalPaymentAmount = Session("Payment_Amount")
 set resArray = GetShippingDetails( Request.QueryString("token"))
 set resArray = ConfirmPayment( finalPaymentAmount )

 ack = UCase(resArray("ACK"))

 If ack <> "SUCCESS" Then
  'Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
  ErrorCode = URLDecode( resArray("L_ERRORCODE0"))
  ErrorShortMsg = URLDecode( resArray("L_SHORTMESSAGE0"))
  ErrorLongMsg = URLDecode( resArray("L_LONGMESSAGE0"))
  ErrorSeverityCode = URLDecode( resArray("L_SEVERITYCODE0"))

response.Write("ack = " & ack)
response.Write("ErrorCode = " & ErrorCode)


 Else
  token = resArray("TOKEN") 
  transactionId = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID") 
  transactionType = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE") 
  paymentType = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE")
  orderTime = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME")
  amt    = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT")
  currencyCode = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE")
  taxAmt   = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT")
  paymentStatus = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS")
  pendingReason = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON")
  reasonCode  = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE")

  SQLStmt = "UPDATE [OrderHeader] SET [Status]='Success' WHERE [Token] = '" & token & "';"
  Set RS_OrderHeader01 = Connection01.Execute(SQLStmt)

  SQLStmt = "SELECT * FROM [OrderHeader] WHERE [Token] = '" & token & "';"
  Set RS_OrderHeader02 = Connection01.Execute(SQLStmt)
 End If
%>
```

There is NOTHING returned at all from Paypal. ACK appears to be either empty or NULL.

Can someone provide some clarity as to what is happening here please? Am I missing a key step? Are there any known issues? Is it likely to be a Sandbox issue?

Kind Regards,

Comment: If you remove on error resume next what error do you see? One more thing try to do URLDecode(resArray instead of your URLDecode( resArray

Comment: by the way how do you think your resArray would react if you pass to it string value (  5  ) instead of integer or money (5). This is on top of your really weird attempt to retrieve ack value from array you just reset to a single value of money. Set Array without index will reset array to the last value you run and index 0.